# Plotting Vasicek Model. Only size -1 arrays can be converted to python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, plot

Attempting to the plot Vasiceks Portfolio loss distribution and when I want to build an array of numbers for x between 0 and 1 for each time step I am having problems.

```
x.astype(int) 
x = np.arange(0.000001, 1, 0.000001)
a1 = math.sqrt((1-rho)/rho)
a2 = -1/(2*rho)*((math.sqrt(1-rho)*norm.ppf(x)-norm.ppf(p)))**2
a3 = ((1/2)*norm.ppf(x))**2

lossdist = a1*math.exp(a2+a3))
```

Above is my model but when I run it it gets to the `lossdist` function and halts, producing

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I have taken a look at the several answers to this previous problem but nothing is working, attempting the `x.astype(int)` and `np.vectorise` solutions. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

math.exp works only on scalar inputs but you're passing an array as an input. You should use numpy.exp since it accepts an array as input.

Reference : `https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html`